# CSS | Two Background

Tags: css

I have wordpress site, and i want change background, and i need two images to background
Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5yLQ.png 
I want it to body, code is now that:

```
body {
    background: #fff;
    color: #494949;
    font-family: Arial,Trebuchet MS,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    background: url(images/bg1.png) top left repeat-x #D3D5D4;
}
```

What i need add here?
i think bg2 need to fit to screen (site)

Answer (score 1):

Seperate it into two div and apply different background for each div

Comment: Can you say how? iam need example plz

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/E9A6y/. Post your HTML if you want to be more specific about your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set seperate background to `html` element and seperate one to `body` element.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS3 tricks, you can apply multiple background to only one div. See this example :

```
body{
    background:url(images/img.gif) no-repeat left top, 
    url(images/img.gif) no-repeat right top, 
    url(images/img.gif) no-repeat left bottom, 
    url(images/img.gif) no-repeat right bottom;
}
```

Careful with browsers compatibility. Hope it helped ;)